# Html form submit button not calling succes method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, button

Html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactfrm" onsubmit="contactus()">

<fieldset class="scheduler-border">

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend class="scheduler-border">Fill contact details</legend>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>  
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="fname" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control input-md" title="Enter your First Name" required="required"></div>
</div>
<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>  
<div class="col-md-6"><input id="lname" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control input-md" title="Enter your Last Name" required="required"></div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
                   <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit" />
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
 </form>
```

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function contactus(){
    alert("hi");
    var test = JSON.stringify({
       "help": $('#help').val(),    
       "firstName": $('#fname').val(), 
       "lastName":$('#lname').val()
       });

    alert("test values are"+test);
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: 'application/json',
           url: baseurl+"contact/add",
           data: test,
           dataType:"text",
           success:successmethod,
           error: function(data,status) 
           {
            alert("Error  "+status);
           }
       });

   }

   function successmethod(data){
    document.getElementById("contactfrm").reset();
    $('#showcontactmessage').show();
    alert("Contact Details Saved");
   }
   </script>
```

Anchor tag:

```
<a href="javascript:contactus();" class="btn btn-success">Contact us now</a>
```

In the above form when i use anchor tag to submit the form every thing works fine ie; the function is called and the values are saved in database and success method is called and executed.but the problem here is, when i use button tag to submit form values, the values are saved in databse but the succes method  is not called instead it calling error method..Any help would be appreciated??

Comment: What is the need of the submit button.

Comment: @AravindSivam Am using submit because when i used required attribute for validations the form is calling contactus directly instead of validating...

Comment: You can go for Quentin answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The submit handler does not prevent the form from submitting.

The JavaScript will run, then the form will immediately submit. The browser will leave the current page and load a new one before it gets the response to the Ajax request. The event handler won't exist on the new page.

You need to prevent the default form action. Using the 90s style approach you are taking, you need to return `false` from the event handler.

```
onsubmit="contactus(); return false;"
```

Comment: @Quentin excellent working fine but can i know 2014 approach style??